# How to highlight my current position in list-view using text-view tags generated dynamically on list-item click

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, textview, listviewitem

My activity flow is this way.

```
**Main ListView**--- list item click

 SubListview- Listitem_1          (parent name-Group)
           Listitem_2

 childListview         Onclick Listitem_1 or 2:     
                             New ListView-new_list_item_1    (parent name-Party)
                                         -new_list_item_2

 grandchildlistview         Onclick new_list_item_1 or 2: 
                   Generate Final-List_view having n elements (parent name-Party name)
```

Now I have taken a linear layout which will be above list view below the toolbar.

I have created a method of **headerTextviewpath** that will trigger from on-item click of Listitem_1 or 2 and will generate a dynamic text-view.

Here in this method textview will be set with text of item clicked parent name

**My linear layout genrated is shown below**

**Group > Party > Party name**

**now I have done this all and have also assigned color to the text-view generating dynamically.**

**Goal::** I want to highlight the last selected parent name in linear layout in different color then the other textview in linear layout like this

**SubListview>**                     (on main list item click)

SubListview> **childListview>**          (Onclick Listitem_1 or 2)

SubListview> childListview> **grandchildlistview**    (Onclick new_list_item_1 or 2)

**Note:** I am adding parent name as tags in textview and also storing it in arraylist namely **tag_list**

Code For Dynamic Textview generating:::::

method is called like this :

```
ArrayList tag_list=new ArrayList;

headerTextviewpath(listitem_seleted_name, functionName, true);
```

**headerTextviewpath**

```
    public void headerTextviewpath(final String listitem_selected, String parent_name, boolean b) {
    if (b) {
            linearLayout.removeAllViews();
        }
        final TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setLayoutParams(new 
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        //tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_design);
        tv.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.DateTheme));
        tv.setText(listitem_selected);

        Drawable next = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_keyboard_arrow_right);
        DrawableCompat.setTint(next, ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPos6));
        tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, next, null);
        tv.setTag(parnet_name);
        tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPos3));
        tag_list.add(parnet_name);

        tv.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

        linearLayout.addView(tv);

       ///using this i am getting current tag of current textview
        int childCount = linearLayout.getChildCount();
        String currentModule = tag.get(childCount - 1);

}
```

How can I make a logic for the above requirement please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all as I passed the values in the array list and also sending a flag it all notes down **to a condition where my current funtion name matches the function name that is added in the array list** so with that i created a simple function for it below, in the method.

```
public void headerTextviewpath(final String displayText, String functionCall, boolean b) {

        if (b) {
            linearLayout.removeAllViews();
        }
        linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setFocusable(true);
        tv.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        //tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_design);
        tv.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.DateTheme));
        tv.setText(FromHtml.getText(displayText));

        Drawable next = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_keyboard_arrow_right);
        DrawableCompat.setTint(next, ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPos6));
        tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, next, null);
        tv.setTag(functionCall);
        tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPos3));
        tag.add(functionCall);

        tv.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

        linearLayout.addView(tv);


        int childCount = linearLayout.getChildCount();


        Object tagObj = linearLayout.getChildAt(0).getTag();
        Log.e("TagObj", "==>" + tagObj.toString() + childCount);

        final String currentModule = tag.get(childCount - 1);
        //  Log.e("TagObjCurr","==>"+currentModule+" "+functionName);
        for (int i = 0; i < tag.size(); i++) {

            Log.e("MoudelFound==>" + i, "tag.get(i):" + tag.get(i) + "  currentModule:" + currentModule);

            if (tag.get(i).equals(currentModule)) {
                tv = linearLayout.findViewWithTag(currentModule);
                tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPos3));
                tv.requestFocus();

            } else {

                tv = linearLayout.findViewWithTag(tag.get(i));
                tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));

            }
        }
 }
```

Finally it worked fine and showing the correct path as well and you can also show the color code to determine the difference.